# JAVA 11 - Optional - Invalid method reference method isPresent in class Optional - Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, lambda, static, option-type, java-11

I don't understand why when I build my project I have this error

> Error:(118, 17) java: incompatible types: invalid method reference method isPresent in class java.util.Optional cannot be applied to given types required: no arguments found: com.siplec.matricee.adresse.model.AdresseVersion reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

#### My code :

```
var optionalAdresseVersion = adresseVersionRepository
    .findByIdVersionAndDeletedDateIsNull(idVersion);

var idAdresse = optionalAdresseVersion
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get);
```

#### Method -  findByIdVersionAndDeletedDateIsNull

I use the interface JpaRepository

```
@Repository
public interface AdresseVersionRepository extends JpaRepository<AdresseVersion, AdresseVersionFk> {

Optional<AdresseVersion> findByIdVersionAndDeletedDateIsNull(String idVersion);
}
```

#### Object -  AdresseVersion

```
@IdClass(value = AdresseVersionFk.class)
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADRESSE_VERSION")
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"idAdresse", "idVersion"})
public class AdresseVersion extends AbstractAuditingEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ADRESSE_FK")
  private String idAdresse;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID_ADRESSE_VERSION")
  private String idVersion;

  @Column(name = "DELETED_DATE")
  private ZonedDateTime deletedDate;
}
```

Also I don't understand the error message from IntelliJ IDEA when I tried to used my Object Optional :

> "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: You can't call an instance method from a static method or block, plain and simple. You likely need to check if any methods called in those contexts are instance-based.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because the method `filter()` takes a predicate that is applicable to the type contained inside the optional, not on the optional itself.

To fix the problem:

It depends what you want to get in `idAdresse` when it's not present. Here I'll assume you want to leave it null:

```
var idAdresse = optionalAdresseVersion
    .map(AdresseVersion::getIdAdresse)
    .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

`optionalAdresseVersion`'s type is `Optional<AdresseVersion>`, `filter` parameter type is `Predicate<? super AdresseVersion>`

```java
var idAdresse = optionalAdresseVersion
    .map(AdresseVersion::getIdAdresse).orElse(null);
```